# Український відповідник до слова "флешка"

Tags: іменники, запозичені-слова, відповідник

Цікавить, чи є рідний відповідник до запозиченого слова "*флешка*", інформації офіційної не знайшла ніде, бо слово відносно нове. Єдине, то є обговорення на сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/fleshka), однак до єдиної думки не дійшли, завжди є нюанси: "*не кожна флешка світлячок", "шпиндик - то є розмовне слово на позначення людини малого зросту, дитинчати також. Але жодного натяку на ПК приспособу" та ін*. До того ж, зауважу, що це лише суб’єктивні висування для заміни.

*Проте чи є у якомусь словнику вже відповідник до слова **флешка***?

Comment: Зазначу, шчо анґліјськоју [звучить](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive) ріжними способами: _USB flash drive_, also variously known as a _thumb drive_, _pen drive_, _gig stick_, _flash stick_, _jump drive_, _disk key_, _disk on key_ (after the original M-Systems DiskOnKey drive from 2000), _flash-drive_, _memory stick_ (not to be confused with the Sony Memory Stick), _USB stick_, _USB memory_. Можете від цього відштовхуватисьа.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Накопичувач` та похідні - `флеш-накопичувач` або USB-накопичувач (`flash drive` або `USB flash drive`), `зовнішній накопичувач` (`hard drive`).

В Словник.ua є [накопичувач](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87), в СУМ - не знайшов.

Більшість онлайн магазинів, що продають техніку, також [використовують](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS795US795&oq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l2j0l3.1784j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) слово `накопичувач`.

Answer (score 0):

Назву flash запропонував Shoji Ariizumi, колега винахідника Fujio Masuoka, тому, що процес стирання нагадував йому спалах камери. В flash-пам'яті використовуються спеціальні [транзистори із плавним затвором](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%96%D0%B7_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC), які зберігають певний заряд навіть коли на них не подається напруга. Для зтирання блока таких транзисторів, у flash-пристроях вони зтираються лише блоками, використовується електричний імпульс. Тому це й нагадує спалах.

Отже, пропоную зробити такі заміни:

- флеш-пам'ять - спалах-пам'ять
- флешка - спалахуйка

Comment: Чому саме наросток _ка_ до _спалахувати_?  Також чому: _Назв**а** flash запропонував_, _**з**тираються_, _**з**тирання_, _транзистори **і**з плавним затвором_, _коли **на** них_. До сьуди шче мајемо багато канцельарізму, тому шче складніше читати, мовчу про зрозуміти. Також було б добре підсилити [џерелами](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujio_Masuoka).

Comment: @follower я був би радив пропозиціям інших словоформ замість або на додачу до *спалахуйка*